# How to build a mode in ace?

Tags: ace-editor

I've create a mode using http://ace.c9.io/tool/mode_creator.html

What is the process to build that into a useable file for an existing version of ace? It seems like maybe I have to pass that code through some sort of build step to get output such as https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/src/mode-golang.js ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it to work:

1. Checked out ace from github
2. Made bosun.js which contained some sort of loading boilerplate - I based on the d example. I then placed might highlight rules in bosun_highlight_rules.js.
3. Ran `node ./Makefile.dryice.js -nc` to build ace , and copied the resulting bosun.js (which has embedded various requirements) to my ace directory in my project. The built file ends up in `/build/src-noconflict/mode-bosun.js`.

bosun.js (pre build, in `/lib/ace/mode` of the repo:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
"use strict";

var oop = require("../lib/oop");
var TextMode = require("./text").Mode;
var BosunHighlightRules = require("./bosun_highlight_rules").BosunHighlightRules;

var Mode = function() {
    this.HighlightRules = BosunHighlightRules;
};

oop.inherits(Mode, TextMode);

(function() {
    this.$id = "ace/mode/bosun";
}).call(Mode.prototype);

exports.Mode = Mode;
});
```

bosun_highlight_rules.js (Also in `/lib/ace/mode`):

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
"use strict";

var oop = require("../lib/oop");
var TextHighlightRules = require("./text_highlight_rules").TextHighlightRules;

var BosunHighlightRules = function() {

    this.$rules = {
        "start" : [
            {....
};

oop.inherits(BosunHighlightRules, TextHighlightRules);

exports.BosunHighlightRules = BosunHighlightRules;
});
```